# How to placing outgoing calls for CCXML and VoiceXML?

Tags: ivr, vxml, ccxml

How to get outgoing call in in IVR? there are use **HP OCMP-RM** for call initiation request. I want to "Caller calls an 123 number and after some interaction with an IVR system places and outbound call to a friend". How I get it?

Answer (score 0):

In VXML you have tag `<transfer>` which will transfer the call to route destination. Please note this will work only with full license Voice platform.

```
<transfer name="mycall" dest="tel:+1-555-123-4567"
      transferaudio="music.wav" connecttimeout="60s" bridge="true">
</transfer>
```

Comment: I got another way. I fill answer  after.